# Accessing elements from a Dictionary plist

Tags: iphone, dictionary

I'm trying to make use of a dictionary plist as shown below:
[image]

I read it into a temp dictionary just fine.

What I'd like to know is if there is an easy way to get at the string children (which are actually a single element in an array, as you can see).

I initially tried objectAtIndex but that was, of course, returning an array, not the string value. I next tried using an NSEnumerator (an objectEnumerator) and then use objectAtIndex:0 to get me the string which does work.

But I'm really hoping there is an easier way to do that.

Edit: clarifying what I'm trying to do.

I want to use the key values (e.g. "All Items") to populate a tableview cell.text and then use the string values (e.g. "find.png") in order to help populate cell.image via UIImage imageNamed:. I would prefer NOT to use hard-coded values (such as objectForKey:@"All Items") so that I can change the data in the plist without also making code changes.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Will there be more than one item in these arrays that you're interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `objectForKey:` on the dictionary to get one of the arrays, and then call `objectAtIndex:0` (or just `lastObject`) on the array to get the string. You can combine these two method calls into one line of code, for example:

```
[[dictionary objectForKey:@"All Items"] lastObject];
```

Comment: I think he wants them all... that's just the same as what he did except using lastObject instead of objectAtIndex:0.

Comment: I guess I need to clarify further. I'm trying to avoid using hard-coded strings like in objectForKey. The whole idea is to allow for the possibility of changing the content of the plist without having to also make a code change. What I'm trying to do with the above data is populate a table view cell.text (with the key values) and use the 'buried' string values (like 'find.png') to add an image to cell.image via UIImage imageNamed.

Comment: The reference to lastObject does help a bit, although still not the most elegant way I'd like to do this.

Comment: Then don't use an array. Use a string as a key and a string as a value. Then you can just get all the keys either through fast enumeration or the allKeys message and use objectForKey with the variable key to populate the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fast enumeration of the dictionary:

```
for (id key in dict) {
    NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [array objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DecisionName.plist"];
    NSLog(@"Error in dictionary");
    NSLog(@"HELLO");
    NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    NSArray *testChoice = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[plistDict objectForKey:selectedDecision]];
    self.choices = [testChoice objectAtIndex:0];
    self.preferences = [testChoice objectAtIndex:1];


This code will be helpful which use to get values from plist having following structure......

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <array>
        <string>Toyota</string>
        <string>Honda</string>
    </array>
    <array>
        <string>Speed</string>
        <string>Reliability</string>
        <string>Price</string>
    </array>
</array>
</plist>
```